# Start cargo with already deployed WAR

Tags: maven-cargo

I'm working with a plugin mechanism of a web application which is deployed locally with cargo. So I mostly do changes in the plugin and not in the application (the WAR) itself. But when starting cargo it deploys the WAR file each time even there were no modifications.
Can cargo be configured this way that it, let’s say reuses the already deployed war file to save time?

My current mvn file:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
   <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
   ...
    <deployables>
        <deployable>
           <location>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</location>
           <pingURL>http://localhost:8080</pingURL>
           <properties>
              <context></context>
           </properties>
         </deployable>
    </deployables>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cargo.tomcat.copywars parameter for that which is by default true.
http://cargo.codehaus.org/Configuration+properties